# computer sleep/wakeup click sound - healthy for monitors?

Tags: monitors, safety

hi,

whenever i put my macbook pro to sleep and wake it up, Core Audio / my sound card seem to restart and i get this glitch/click sound on my monitors... sometimes i hear a single one and at other times it's like a sequence of a few. i'm wondering if this is healthy for the monitors?

the only thing that links my monitors with the macbook pro is a firewire sound card (edirol fa-66) - no mixers or anything on the way.

thanks,
k

Answer (score 1):

Mine does that too, I quickly learned to mute my mbox mini every time I leave the computer or shut the lid on my laptop or restart it.  Not sure if the phenomenon is malicious.

Answer (score 1):

To plainly answer your question, it can't be healthy. It will become unhealthy if it is loud and you never learn the lesson.

I have a pair of Adam A7's fed by my MBox2 Mini. I used to forget switching off my monitors before the MBox and the distortion of one of my ribbon tweeters around 3kHz might be a result of this (or a result of my buying second hand). Now I'll turn the volume knob all the way down as well as switching on the mute switch before I start/stop/put to sleep my machine.

Comment: Do you re-calibrate your monitors every day, or do you just kind of know where they should be for 0db?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing that fancy, I merely set them "loud enough", trying to reproduce the apparent SPL I get at my local cinema. I'm also in a small untreated room so exact calibration is not quite feasible yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a spike caused by the signal suddenly being cut off. I doubt it'll blow everything up (unless maybe you have your monitors cranked), but it's always a good idea to turn your monitors on last, and off first. Also, i'm not sure if you're using PT at all, but DigiDesign don't recommend letting your computer go to sleep while running their software.